# ssh - How to Redirect Error on Host to a file on the Client

Tags: ssh, io-redirection

I'm executing a command on a host machine from a bash script using ssh like this:

```
ssh pi@rasp 'rm /home/pi/webcam/rmtest.txt' || \
{ echo "remove  failed" > $log;  }
```

It works as desired except if there is an error on the host it is redirected to the client:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/pi/webcam/rmtest.txt’: No such file or directory
```

I would like to redirect that error message to a file on the client, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I tried putting:

**>$log 2>&1**

in various places, but nothing worked.

The variable $log:

```
pi@raspsky:~/webcam $ echo $log
/home/pi/webcam/condtest.log
```

Comment: Edit question to tell us: Which various places? and what is in variable `$log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh pi@rasp 'rm /home/pi/webcam/rmtest.txt' 2> $log
```

ssh connects the remote stdin, stdout and stderr descriptors to the local ones, so just redirect the local stderr as required.